# Get request.user object

Tags: python, django, model

Is it possible to get the request.user object in a function defined for a model. For example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   description = models.TextField()
   author = models.ForeignKey(User)

   def has_upvoted(self):
      return Up.objects.filter(user = self.request.user,
                          event = self.id)
```

I am using django's 'User' model which allows 'request.user' to return the user object. Is it possible to get it in the above function '**has_upvoted()**'. Also, the seconf filter used in the function above takes an instance of the 'Event' model itself. What I've written is wrong. So, whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need M2M field for votes. Something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    voted_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='voted_events')
```

Then you can use it:

```
request.user.voted_events.all()
```

or

```
if specified_event in request.user.voted_events:
    print "%s up voted by %s" % (specified_event.description, request.user.username)
```

Your `has_upvoted()` method is not good idea.

Comment: This model doesn't suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is not very nice, please see it:

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2179/

I don't know another way

Comment: Explicitly passing the user as argument looks like a very obvious way to me... The hack you link to is really very very bad practice by all standards.

Comment: Yeah this is very obvious and easy... I replied it because the question was another, she updated the question.

Comment: cf James Bennett's blog (http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/) : "(...) what’s known as the “threadlocal hack”; this basically involves sticking request.user into a sort of magical globally-available variable, and is a Very Bad Thing to use if you don’t know what you’re doing. It’s also generally a Very Bad Thing to use even if you do know what you’re doing, since you’re probably just doing it because you’re lazy and don’t feel like ensuring you pass information around properly. So if you see someone suggesting that you do this using a “threadlocal”, ignore that person."

Answer (score 0):

Models can be used outside the http request / response cycle (management commands etc) so you cannot assume there's a globally available `request` object. The only clean way to make "the current request.user" available to you model's methods is to explicitly pass it as argument. This will also make your code more testable and more robust.

```
class Event(models.Model):
   description = models.TextField()
   author = models.ForeignKey(User)

   # strange naming... looks like a predicate
   # but acts as a getter ???

   def has_upvoted(self, user):
      return Up.objects.filter(
          user=self.request.user,
          event=self.id)
```

Then in your view:

```
def whatever(request, ...):
    event = get_your_event(...)
    ups = event.has_upvoted(request.user)
```

If you need a direct access from templates you'll have to wrap the call in a custom template tag or filter, depending on what `has_upvoted` is really supposed to be (predicate or accessor)

the templatetag version:

```
# yourapp/templatags/whatever.py
@register.assignement_tag
def has_upvoted(event, user):
    return event.has_upvoted(user)
```

and then

```
# yourtemplates/whatever.html

{% has_upvoted evt request.user as whatever %}
{{ whatever }}
```

more about custom tags and filters here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: I beg your pardon ? Are you saying you don't know how to pass an argument to a method ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No, I'm saying that I didn't understand your solution. I need to access the function from template and one cannot pass an argument to a method from templates. So, still I  haven't figured it out.

Comment: @Monique: then you have to write either a filter or templatetag.